# Java Reflection : avoid fields with default values

Tags: java, json, reflection

I have the following class structure:

```
public Class A{
private int a;
private String b;
private B binst;
}

public Class B{
private int x;
private String y;
}
```

All the getters and setters are defined. I use Java reflection to invoke as follows :

```
method.invoke(ClassAObj, ClassBObj);
```

Now, before invoking this, I had only set `y` and not `x`. I convert this ClassAObj into JSON and find that the default value of `0` is set for `x`, and it appears in the JSON. I don't want `x` field to appear in the JSON. How should I avoid this?

Interestingly, if I set `x` and not `y`, the tag `y` doesn't appear in the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `int` is a primitive, i.e: not nullable, and usually `Json` parsers discard null values.
You can use the `reference` type `Integer` and its default will be `null` .

```
public Class B{
  private Integer x;
  private String y;
}
```