# JSON: Make Jackson only serialise fields that were explicitly set for an object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a Java Object that I want to serialise to JSON. However, before I do that, I set some properties on fields for that object. Now I want to serialise this object to JSON. How can I serialise only the fields that were explicitly assigned a value and basically exclude all other fields?

For me, adding these annotations above the object class do not work: `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)` and `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`. The reason is that I have fields with primitive data types. By adding one of the above two annotations, I am not preventing primitive data type fields from being serialised. For example, I have several boolean fields that will be serialised with their default value `false`. However, I do not want these fields to appear in the JSON result, as I have not explicitly set their values before the serialisation process. Any thoughts?

For further information: I am using the Jackson ObjectMapper.

Comment: How could Jackson make a distinction betwee a false attribute which is false because it's its default value, and an attribute which is false because you've set it to false?

Comment: I believe that this is the underlying problem for which I need a solution! Perhaps I need to configure the object mapper manually and tell it the fields I want to have explicitly. There does not seem to be any other way in this case.

Comment: might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388697/java-reflection-avoid-fields-with-default-values/33388772#33388772

Comment: I thought about this as well. Essentially, I would have no primitives anymore; I cannot really gauge if that is the outcome I would necessarily want to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Jackson 2.6, use [`@JsonInclude`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) with [`Include.NON_DEFAULT`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT).

> Value that indicates that only properties that have values that differ
>   from default settings (meaning values they have when Bean is
>   constructed with its no-arguments constructor) are to be included.

Jackson will create an throwaway instance of your class so it can verify which property values are different from the defaults, and only serialize those.

Comment: That seems to be a good solution. However, what if I set one of the boolean fields to false explicitly?

Comment: @KevinWu If `false` was the default value for that property, then it won't serialize it.

Comment: Hi, do you have any workaround on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @kevinWu Instead of a POJO, use a `Map` type (or create an `ObjectNode` directly) and set only values for the keys you want.

Comment: Easiest way here would be to use `Boolean`, which allows leaving default as `null`.